# How to properly access the list of rooms a socket is connected to in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, sockets, socket.io

so I'm trying to get send a notification to specific rooms when the user disconnects from socket server. I have this on my server side:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    for (room of socket.rooms) {
        console.log("Found a room: " + room)
        //going to try to emit to the rooms the client is connected to here.
    }
    console.log("DISCONNECTED USER: " + socket.id);
});
```

This should print out a list of the rooms the socket is currently connected to but when I have the socket join a room and then disconnect, all that prints out is "DISCONNECTED USER: myID." Not entirely sure how to go about this.

Comment: Sockets connect to sockets not rooms

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Sorry, I'm very new to this. I thought socket.rooms would access the list of rooms a socket is in, AKA the sockets it is connected to? I also tried to iterate through socket.sockets but that also did not work...not sure why, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is that `socket.rooms` has already been emptied at the time the disconnect event handler is fired.

Comment: FYI, you're not supposed to edit the title to "SOLVED" here at stackoverflow.  Leave the title the way it was as a question.  The accepted answer indicates that your problem is solved.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I changed it back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `socket.rooms` has already been emptied at the time the disconnect event handler is fired.

The only way I know of to work around that would be to keep your own separate record of what rooms you put the socket in.  Since it is only your server that can put it in a room, you would have access to the code that adds or removes it from rooms.  Then, when you get the `disconnect` event, you would have your own list of the rooms you put it in.

Here's an example:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.myRooms = new Set();

    // whatever message you use to add a socket to a room
    socket.on('addToRoom', (roomName) => {
         socket.join(roomName);

         // update our shadow copy of the rooms list
         socket.myRooms.add(roomName);
    });

    // whatever message you use to remove a socket from a room
    socket.on('removeFromRoom', (roomName) => {
         socket.leave(roomName);

         // update our shadow copy of the rooms list
         socket.myRooms.delete(roomName);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        for (let room of socket.myRooms) {
            console.log("Found a room: " + room)
            io.to(room).emit(...);
        }
        console.log("DISCONNECTED USER: " + socket.id);             
    });
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!